# How to update header parameters from filter with Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a filter with Spring security which *extends* of 
`OncePerRequestFilter` class and It has to update parameters in the REST service .Parameters are entered by the header with the annotation `@RequestHeader`.

I have tried to update parameters from the filter with the follows class:

```
public class HeaderMapRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    /**
     * construct a wrapper for this request
     * 
     * @param request
     */
    public HeaderMapRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    private Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    /**
     * add a header with given name and value
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param value
     */
    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        headerMap.put(name, value);
    }

    public void removeteHeader(String name){
        headerMap.remove(name); 
    }
    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String headerValue = super.getHeader(name);
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            headerValue = headerMap.get(name);
        }
        return headerValue;
    }

    /**
     * get the Header names
     */
    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
        for (String name : headerMap.keySet()) {
            names.add(name);
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(names);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
        List<String> values = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            values.add(headerMap.get(name));
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(values);
    }

}
```

And with the method `.addHeader("parameter", "New value")`, but when I read the parameter in the method it has not changed, but if  read it from .getHeader("parameter") method from *HttpServletRequest* class, which I have inyected in the same method class. The changes are done, but in the method parameters not appear.

The method is the follows:

```
@Autowired
HttpServletRequest a;


//Annotations @GetMapping......
public void method (@RequestHeader(value="Parameter") String parameter){
      System.out.print(parameter); //Parameter did not change
      system.out.print(a.getHeader("parameter"));    //Parameter changed.
}
```

Does Someone know how to change the operation parameters from a filter?, or from other way....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong but when I try it with my setup it seems to work. Please take a look at the following code.

```
/**
 * username: test, password: test
 * Added Header: param
 * REST URL: http://localhost:8080/hello
 */

package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestRequestWrapperApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestRequestWrapperApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
class RequestWrapperFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HeaderMapRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest)request);
        wrappedRequest.addHeader("param", "Hello World!");

        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
    }
}

@RestController
class TestRest {
    @GetMapping("hello")
    public String hello(@RequestHeader("param") String param) {
        return "param: " + param;
    }
}

@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").authorities("test").password("test");
    }
}

class HeaderMapRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public HeaderMapRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    private Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        headerMap.put(name, value);
    }

    public void removeteHeader(String name) {
        headerMap.remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String headerValue = super.getHeader(name);
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            headerValue = headerMap.get(name);
        }
        return headerValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
        for (String name : headerMap.keySet()) {
            names.add(name);
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(names);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
        List<String> values = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            values.add(headerMap.get(name));
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(values);
    }

}
```

Comment: it works!!!!, the mistake was because of the parameter header is very long and it is in base64 and when I used the addHeader method, the new value was concatenated to the older one and I did not notice it.

The solution was update the getHeaders method of the HeaderMapRequestWrapper class with the line code `values.clear()`

Thanks for your help.