# Spring Hateoas linkto is relying on Host request header. how to avoid it and use the host from request URL?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-hateoas

Request am sending:

```
GET https://example.com/testing/123456
Request header:
 HOST: abcd.com
```

Response i got:

```
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://abcd.com/data/api/customers"
        }
    }
```

is there a way i get Response as

```
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://example.com/data/api/customers"
        }
    }
```

Using Hateoas 0.25.1.RELEASE

**href should not take Request Host Header**

Answer (score 0):

One way is to override the getServerName:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component 
public class RequestWrapperFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    @Value("${com.awgtek.host}")
    protected String basePath;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HeaderMapRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    class HeaderMapRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        HeaderMapRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getServerName() {
            return basePath;
        }
    }
}
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47679098/1527469